# Mongo setup not allowing transactions

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, transactions

I'm getting this exception when adding Transactional to Spring mongo code.

`Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoClientException: Transactions are not supported by the MongoDB cluster to which this client is connected`

This is my code: @Configuration

```
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = { "com.repository" })
public class MongoConfig  extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.uri}")
    private String connection;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
    private String database;

    @Autowired
    MongoProperties mongoProperties;

    @Bean
    MongoTransactionManager transactionManager(MongoDatabaseFactory dbFactory) {
        return new MongoTransactionManager(dbFactory);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "hendrix";
    }

    @Override
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        final ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString(connection);
        final MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
                .build();
        return MongoClients.create(mongoClientSettings);
    }
}
```

How do I add replicas to a barebones Mongo setup I have access to? If the cluster is on AWS what setting would I have to change?

Comment: If you are not running Mongo 4.0 or later, then Spring Mongo will be unable to support transactions.

Comment: Transactions are not supported on standalone topology, I guess you use it, then configure replica set or sharded